# how to pass variable inside a for loop with was is single quote

Tags: python, for-loop, subprocess

Can anyone tell how to pass stored variable inside the quotes.

```
for name in names_list:
    p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe",'-Command','&{."Local drive url"; &Function(name)}'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
    result = p.communicate()[0]`
```

Could you any one can guide me here.

Thank you

Comment: you can use string processing or regex to get the result as you know the name of variable

Comment: Maybe you can try to use f-string to format the string in order to get `name` variable into your string.  Reference: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: I have tried the both regex and f-string, for f-string it give attribute error like 'list' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: I'm not sure what the **`communicate`** function and the square brackets `[0]` indexing method are returning, but I would recommend you unpack 2 variables, **`err, out`** and explore the results `out, err = p.communicate()` ... `print(out)`

Comment: It's unclear. You need to provide a [mre], including sample data. Anyway, do you want ```'&{."Local drive url"; &Function(' + name + '})}'```?